# MS SQL query not working on MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server

I have a query working on MS SQL Server, but not working on MySQL:

```
SELECT ppmap_d.*, p_prob.*, ppmap_h.*, p_probgroup.*,
 p_prod.*, ppmap_d.prob_id AS probid, ppmap_d.map_id AS mapid, 
 ppmap_h.pg_name AS probgname, ppmap_h.m_id AS modelid
FROM p_prob 
INNER JOIN p_prod 
INNER JOIN ppmap_h 
INNER JOIN ppmap_d 
INNER JOIN p_probgroup 
ON ppmap_d.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id 
ON ppmap_h.map_id = ppmap_d.map_id AND ppmap_h.pg_name = p_probgroup.pg_name 
ON p_prod.m_id = ppmap_h.m_id 
ON p_prob.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id;
```

What did I do wrong?

The query below is correct but results in an error:

```
SELECT ppmap_d.*, p_prob.* 
FROM ppmap_d INNER JOIN p_probgroup 
ON ppmap_d.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id;
```

**Error:**

> SELECT ppmap_d.*, p_prob.* FROM ppmap_d INNER JOIN p_probgroup ON ppmap_d.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id LIMIT 0, 25
>   MySQL said: Documentation
>
> 1051 - Unknown table 'dbeshop.p_prob'

Comment: can you post the Error

Comment: Your query will not work on any DB engine! Put the correct `on` clause behind every JOIN and not all of them at the end

Comment: how can i post here error there is no option in stackoverflow

Comment: SQL query: Documentation


SELECT ppmap_d.*, p_prob.*, ppmap_h.*, p_probgroup.*,
 p_prod.*, ppmap_d.prob_id AS probid, ppmap_d.map_id AS mapid, 
 ppmap_h.pg_name AS probgname, ppmap_h.m_id AS modelid
FROM p_prob 
INNER JOIN p_prod  ON ppmap_d.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id 
INNER JOIN ppmap_h ON ppmap_h.map_id = ppmap_d.map_id AND ppmap_h.pg_name = p_probgroup.pg_name 
INNER JOIN ppmap_d ON p_prod.m_id = ppmap_h.m_id 
INNER JOIN p_probgroup ON p_prob.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id LIMIT 0, 25
MySQL said: Documentation

#1054 - Unknown column 'ppmap_d.prob_id' in 'on clause'

Comment: You've got circular joins, you're joining ppmap_h and ppmap_d so that they both depend upon each other, you can't do this. You can't call either of them because they both depend on the other one, you'd have to call one of the tables twice for this to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ppmap_d.*, p_prob.*, ppmap_h.*, p_probgroup.*,
 p_prod.*, ppmap_d.prob_id AS probid, ppmap_d.map_id AS mapid, 
 ppmap_h.pg_name AS probgname, ppmap_h.m_id AS modelid
FROM p_prob 
INNER JOIN p_prod  ON ppmap_d.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id 
INNER JOIN ppmap_h ON ppmap_h.map_id = ppmap_d.map_id AND ppmap_h.pg_name = p_probgroup.pg_name 
INNER JOIN ppmap_d ON p_prod.m_id = ppmap_h.m_id 
INNER JOIN p_probgroup ON p_prob.prob_id = p_probgroup.prob_id;
```

Comment: please explain the answer in brief what you have modified

Comment: The ON was in the wrong place

Comment: This is the correct answer, you need to keep the join and ON statements together

Comment: after correction this error
#1054 - Unknown column 'ppmap_d.prob_id' in 'on clause'